# Iterate numbers in dart

Tags: loops, dart

Dark issue:

I've input numbers as 10 20 35 11 without comma.
I need to take this numbers as input and and put them in List. How can I do that?
I search a lot but I did not get any resource like this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yes, I'm new in Dart

Comment: It is usually helpful to show your best good faith attempt code with the question, along with details of your problems with this attempt, and then use this code and problem to help make the question more specific and helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string with the list of numbers:

```
final input = "10 20 35 11";
```

You can [split the string](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html), and then [parse the numbers](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/parse.html) with something like:

```
final list = input.split(" ").map((str) => int.parse(str));
```